# Get Token error in azure

Tags: c#, azure, token, bots, adfs

I have created mvc project, in this project i will call a webapi to fetch data.
I get a token first,the code is as follows:

```
var userCredential = new UserCredential("user@microsoft.com");
var redirectUri = new Uri("https://test.com");
var authContext = new 
AuthenticationContext(https://login.windows.net/microsoft.com/", false);
var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("urn://smc.test.prod", ClientId, userCredential).Result;
var token = authResult.AccessToken
```

the code works fine in my local,but when i publish the code to azure, i get the error:

> Federated service at msft.sts.microsoft.com/adfs/services/trust/13/windowstransport returned error: See inner exception for detail.

can anyone help me?

Comment: does your userCredential need a password?

Comment: What does this inner exception say?